# Writing a query in SQLAlchemy to count occurrences and store IDs

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm working with a postgres db using SQLAlchemy.

I have a table like this

```
class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Author"
    id = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Unicode)
```

and I want to identify all homonymous authors and save their id in a list.

For example if in the database there are 2 authors named "John" and 3 named "Jack", with ID respectively 11, 22, 33, 44 a 55, I want my query to return

```
[("John", [11,22]), ("Jack", [33,44,55])]
```

For now I've been able to write

```
[x for x in db_session.query(
          func.count(Author.name),
          Author.name
          ).group_by(Author.name) if x[0]>1]
```

but this just gives me back occurrences

```
[(2,"John"),(3,"Jack")]
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this in SQL would be to use PostgreSQL's `array_agg` function to group the ids into an array:

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    array_agg(id) AS ids
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY
    name
HAVING
    count(name) > 1;
```

The `array_agg` function collects the ids for each name, and the `HAVING` clause excludes those with only a single row.  The output of the query would look like this:

```
 name  │        ids         
═══════╪════════════════════
 Alice │ {2,4,9,10,16}
 Bob   │ {1,6,11,12,13}
 Carol │ {3,5,7,8,14,15,17}
```

Translated into SQLAlchemy, the query would look like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
q = (
    db_session.query(Author.name, sa.func.array_agg(Author.id).label('ids'))
    .group_by(Author.name)
    .having(sa.func.count(Author.name) > 1)
)
```

Calling `q.all()` will return a list of `(name, [ids])` tuples like this:

```py
[
    ('Alice', [2, 4, 9, 10, 16]),
    ('Bob', [1, 6, 11, 12, 13]),
    ('Carol', [3, 5, 7, 8, 14, 15, 17]),
]
```

In SQLAlchemy 1.4/2.0-style syntax equivalent would be:

```py
with Session() as s:
    q = (
        sa.select(Author.name, sa.func.array_agg(Author.id).label('ids'))
        .group_by(Author.name)
        .having(sa.func.count(Author.name) > 1)
    )
    res = s.execute(q)
```